# Laravel 4.2 AJAX post giving me 404 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm still using Laravel 4.2 and I'm trying to post a form with AJAX, but it gives me error 404 for a post page. Here is my code:

routes.php:

```
Route::post('/', array(
    'as' => 'postFora',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@postFora'
));
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function postFora() {

    $form = Input::all();
    $f = New Fora;
    $f->content = Input::get('contant');
    $f->user_id = Input::get('user_id');
    $f->save();

    return Response::json(array('success' => true)); 
}
```

main.js:

```
$('.dodaj-foro').submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/belezka/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

index:

```
<form class="dodaj-foro" action="/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user[0]->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="contant" placeholder="Fora tuki">
</form>
```

Comment: could you please show ur routes.php

Answer (score 0):

In case you did not change the defaults Laravel comes with, add `public` to the AJAX request URL. By default, the route `'/'` corresponds to `http://localhost/belezka/public/` due to URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enter the route in present in Route file instead of http://localhost/belezka/

Try to replace :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/belezka/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    .....
```

By :

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "postFora",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    .....
```

Hope this will help.